# Launching an Angular route gives 404 until Index.html opened

Tags: angular, apache

I have an angular application that is hosted on an Apache server.   I have a Jboss7 application that is getting redirected to this application. I am trying to go to an Angular Route which gives a Not Found until I open Index.HTML.  I can then access the route successfully.  I have an .htaccess file as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html
```

I have tried different .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this.

**Method One: Using hash.**
Apache server will be able to recognize the angular route after the '#' in the URL segment, so it would not go and try to find xxx.html in the hosting server path instead.

```
// app-routing.module.ts

import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
  // NbLoginComponent,
  // NbLogoutComponent,
  // NbRegisterComponent,
  // NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  // NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from '@nebular/auth';
import { VfLoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './@core/utils/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: VfLoginComponent,
        resolve: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: VfLoginComponent,
        resolve: [AuthGuard]
      },
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**Method Two: Update the .htaccess.** 
This is my preferred method. Basically, it does some optimization with gzip (better loading performance) and it fall back to index.html via the route or URL. More info: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

```
#REDIRECT ROUTES TO INDEX (fixes broken routes with angular)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
#ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
# SET EXPIRE HEADERS TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```